# How can I debug a custom transformer

Tags: dart, dart-pub

How can I debug a (custom) transformer using the debugger in DartEditor.

I tried use the transformer shown in http://dovdev.com/smoke-and-mirrors/ but it fails.

I checked these documents but couldn't find anything about debugging.

- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html
- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/index.html

Comment: I've updated the article and the GitHub repo. The transformer should work now. Please open an issue on GitHub if you still have problems with it. I agree that the transformer debugging experience is not too pleasant currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pub runs transformers in its process, inside isolates, and doesn't redirect a transformers stdout, it's fairly hard to debug from within pub itself, so the best option is to run the transformer outside of pub by setting up a barback environment along with mocked files.

The [code_transformers](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/code_transformers) package makes this easier. See its tests library: http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/code_transformers/0.2.3+1/index.html#code_transformers/code_transformers-tests

Comment: `pub` is Dart code, isn't it? Is there no way to connect a debugger to a running Dart script? Is there no way to use this for example with `pause_isolates_on_start` or something?